# Getting the Previous Entry From A Database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a news website with articles and I'm trying to show the next and previous articles at the end of each post.

The next link is working fine but the previous link always shows the first ever post.  Here is the `get` code that I'm using for each:

```
$get_next_sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id > '$article_id' LIMIT 1";
$get_prev_sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id < '$article_id' LIMIT 1";
```

Am I missing something in the `prev` code?

Comment: $get_prev_sql will always shows the first one. There is no error with the code. Error is with your logic only. Please try to order it in descending order since if you limit it without any order by clause,it will take the default ordering style which is ascending which will always shows the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting only posts which have `id` less than current.

By default, Database is sorting with PRIMARY field and IN ASC order.

So, its always returning post with lowest `id`.

What you need is the post lower than current and with highest `id`.

So, the corrected code should be:

```
$get_prev_sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id < '$article_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: @user3177012, if my answer worked for you, please accept it as solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
$get_prev_sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id < '$article_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

default order for primary key is ASC

Answer (score 1):

use this query

```
select * from table_name where id < your_current_id order BY id desc limit 1
```